# jQuery How to get first LI parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I get just the first LI and pass it to var...not cycle through?

```
bind("something", function (event, data) {
            data.inst.get_container().find('li').each(function(i) {             
            my var = this;

<li>  <-- I want this one
<li>
<li>
<li>
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the HTML you have and what you want to select?

Comment: The first moving *up* through the ancestors of an element, *down* through the descendants or laterally through the siblings?

Comment: Do you mean `var myli = $(this).parent().find('li')`? or the parent li `var myli = $(this).parent('li')`?

Comment: In these cases HTML helps so much to get the answer you wish.

Comment: `my var = this;` is not valid javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways, I have setup a fiddle that uses the [.eq() jquery](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method.

```
var firstli = $('li').eq(0);
```

This will grab the first li and place it in an jquery object for you.

If you wan to narrow the selection, just modify the selector:

```
var firstliofparent = $('parentElement li').eq(0);
```

Once you have your selected li and you want to know the parent, just grab the parent() method .

```
firstli.parent();
```

Fiddle here -> http://jsfiddle.net/UzCA9/6/

Answer (score 1):

`$(this).closest('li')` should give you the parent which is the nearest and is a `li`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [jQuery `first`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) method:

```
myVar = data.inst.get_container().find('li').first();
```